# MySQL BETWEEN Index

Tags: mysql, database-indexes

I have to figure out a way whether a number (stored as string because of leading zeros) falls in a specific range. The ranges look like this:

```
12 - 14
3456 - 4567
```

1233435 would be considered to fall in the first range (matching is from the left).The number can have a maximum of 20 digits and I have a file which has all ranges included. I imported the ranges adding trailing zeros to the lower bound and trailing nines to the upper bound to reach the length of 20. This is to be able to handle variable length numbers - they are padded with zeros on the right so that I can do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE 'my padded number' BETWEEN bound_lower AND bound_upper
```

Since I have a couple of thousand ranges I would like to put an index on the table but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

Thanks,
Mendel

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a valid approach that you've taken.  To add the index, you just have to:

```
 CREATE INDEX between_index on ranges (bound_lower, bound_upper);
```

You can verify that it is working by using EXPLAIN.

Comment: :) If I do this MySQL does not use the index at all or if I force it MySQL uses only the bound_lower which is stupid if the bin is on the lower end

Comment: It sounds like you maybe should be asking:  "When I do this query, it is too slow, how can I speed it up?", but what you actually asked was how to add the index.  There are a few techniques for speeding up range queries, which you can find here on SO.  Look for date range query question, the same techniques can be used for your ints.